# Angular ng-repeat not working with deep linking

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I've got an interesting problem happening for me in Angular that I can't seem to find a solution for.

Here is the source: http://plnkr.co/edit/XTXOYn8LcG0yb846lwbS

Basically I am using an ng-repeat to create a vertical sidebar that deep links to a certain part of the page. Now, I've tested the generated code statically, and it works so maybe I'm not doing something right.

Heres is the code, in case you don't want to go to Plunker.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="span3 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked span3">
        <li ng-repeat="rule in rules">
            <a ng-click="scrollTo('{{ rule.name|toId }}')">{{ rule.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span9">
    <div class="rule" ng-repeat="rule in rules">
      <section id="{{ rule.name|toId }}" >
        <header>
          <h1>{{ rule.name }}</h1>
        </header>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.
  filter('toId', function(){
      return function(input){
          var out = "";

          out = input.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

          return out;
      }
  });

app.
  controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rules = [
        {
          'name': 'rule1',
          'desc': 'I am a rule.'
        },
        {
          'name': 'rule2',
          'desc': 'I am a rule.'
        },
        {
          'name': 'rule3',
          'desc': 'I am a rule.'
        }
      ];

      $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
      };
  });
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this expression:

```
<a ng-click="scrollTo('{{ rule.name|toId }}')">{{ rule.name }}</a>
```

You must remember that AngularJS is not a string-based templating engine so you can't just throw `{{expr}}` at random places. Instead you need to write valid expressions according to the syntax described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Fortunately the fix is simple:

```
<a ng-click="scrollTo(rule.name)">{{ rule.name }}</a>
```

and move the filtering logic to a controller:

```
      $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $location.hash(toIdFilter(id));
        $anchorScroll();
      };
```

Working plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QqGW8CC3kRW3t881j0yV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. It seems that this does work for static content on the page but not dynamically generated content using ng-repeat? http://plnkr.co/edit/Lb5qUaTeRZn9D4od4J1Z